# WPF - Is <?Mapping > used anymore?

Tags: wpf, namespaces, assemblies, xml-namespaces

Basically, I remember that there was a time when you could use the following: `<?Mapping ... >` (It doesn't seem to work anymore -- Deprecated perhaps?)

I know I can map my XML namespaces like so...

```
xmlns:xyzcon="clr-namespace:XYZ.Wpf.Controls"
xmlns:xyzcom="clr-namespace:XYZ.Wpf.Commands"
```

But, I also know that I can map my XML namespaces like so (much cleaner)

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.mycompany.com/netfx/xaml/presentation", "xyz")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.mycompany.com/netfx/xaml/presentation", "XYZ.Wpf.Controls")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.mycompany.com/netfx/xaml/presentation", "XYZ.Wpf.Commands")]
```

which makes it very easy to use because instead having the l, lv, etc. prefix I can have all my CLR-Namespaces point to the same XML namespace...

```
xmlns:xyz="http://schemas.mycompany.com/netfx/xaml/presentation"
```

That line gives me access to XYZ.Wpf.Controls and XYZ.Wpf.Commands. The problem is that this only works if the assembly is already compiled. I can't use this trick when working within the same assembly.

Basically, from within the same app or assembly, I want to map different CLR namespaces to the SAME XML namespace on a global scale (that way throughout my app I simply have to include that one XML namespace). Any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there is still no way to map local namespaces within a WPF project. The book [Programming WPF: Building Windows UI with Windows Presentation Foundation](http://books.google.com/books?id=558i6t1dKEAC&pg=PA685&lpg=PA685&dq=XmlnsDefinitionattribute%20same%20assembly&source=bl&ots=gZriLGDSOR&sig=fqi96DvoBlYmPFG5GmzXfUHY_qE&hl=en&ei=fJS6SdGYD4_OMofLnKMI&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=3&ct=result.#v=onepage&q=XmlnsDefinitionattribute%20same%20assembly&f=false) (published in 2007) states:

*WPF projects in Visual Studio cannot use namespaces introduced by `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute` from XAML that live in the same assembly. If you want to refer to locally defined types, you must use the alternative mechanism...*

The "alternative mechanism" being the dreaded `xmlns:local="..."` for each namespace.

My understanding is that the executing assembly (in this case the local WPF assembly) searches all *referenced* assemblies for both `XmlnsPrefixAttribute` and `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute` but does not search itself. It makes no sense that 4 years later this behavior has not changed, but that appears to be the case.

Comment: What about the <?Mapping > tags? Any information out there about them? I can't seem to find anything myself.

Comment: I've personally never seen anything on that tag and I don't ever remember seeing it referenced. Like yourself, I also can find nothing on it, past or present.

Comment: I finally found a MSDN forum post on it, sorta... but not the actual reference to it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/483897bc-9f48-4e4e-b76a-5a8cd402a75e